# Insert line after an XML file

Tags: text-processing, xml

I have a file that contains a small XML snippet. I also have a large XML file. The large XML file has a line that includes `<build>`.

In Bash, How can I insert the contents of the small file after the line that contains `<build>` in a way that it'd still have the new lines of the old file?

Thanks ahead!

Comment: Do you want to include the extra segment inside `<build>...</build>` tree or after it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably a job best suited for an xml parser of some sort, but if you insist on doing it with standard UNIX tools available to bash:

```
sed '/<build>/ r smallfile.xml' bigfile.xml
```

(That'll print to stdout. If you want to change `bigfile.xml` in place, then use `sed -i` at the start.)